# Prompt for Windows credentials in IIS when specific user or host is used

Tags: iis, windows-authentication

I have an IIS site that uses integrated Windows authentication. Today we set up a new conference room with its own dedicated user account for the computer, and people who access the IIS site from this computer/user will not have the proper permissions. Is there a way to deny access to a user or host on IIS with Windows authentication and prompt for credentials instead?

I found that I can force a credential prompt if I call the code below, but no credentials are accepted. The prompt just happens over and over.

```
if (WorkContext.CurrentCustomer.Email == "useremail@domain.com")
{
    Response.StatusCode = 401;
    Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about IIS Authorization Rules?
You can deny "All Users", "All Anonymous", Or "specific users"

Hope that helps.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you, I appreciate it!